# vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [911] Keyboard format is invalid: row 0 contains too much columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

vk_session = VkApi(token="")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, id)
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def create_keyboard(response):
    keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=False)

    if response == '1':

        keyboard.add_button('1', color=VkKeyboardColor.DEFAULT)

    elif response == '2':
        keyboard.add_button('2', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

    elif response == '3':
        keyboard.add_button('3', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

    elif response == '4':
        keyboard.add_button('4', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

    keyboard = keyboard.get_keyboard()
    return keyboard

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        response = event.object['text']
        keyboard = create_keyboard(response)
        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        text = "2"

        vk.messages.send(random_id=random_id,chat_id=chat_id, message='2', keyboard=keyboard)

    elif event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        response = event.object['text']
        keyboard = create_keyboard(response)
        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        text = "1"

        vk.messages.send(random_id=random_id,chat_id=chat_id, message='1', keyboard=keyboard)
```

После написания в беседу появляется сообщение об ошибке 911.

Comment: `row 0 contains too much columns` - переводится как "ряд 0 содержит слишком много колонок". Проверьте, будет ли возникать ошибка, если создать меньше кнопок.

Comment: Сохраняется, даже если кнопка одна будет.